Unable to begin the Dataflow using Apache MiNiFi
I am new to MiNiFi, and started to look out for quick tutorials on how to work with MiNiFi.
Found this cloudera - article and followed the same.
But my MiNiFi is not generating any data to my NiFi instance.
I followed this cloudera - article. Got to know the process of building up a pipeline using NiFi for MiNiFi.
From the quick - start guide of MiNiFi I got know, how to set up the dataflow that has to be run by MiNiFi.
These are things I have done to build the dataflow for MiNiFi:

First I have created a pipeline to read from a table present in my Postgres SQL database using a ExecuteSQL processor, Remote Process Group, Input Port and logAttribute Proccessor.

Pipeline to read from the PSQL table and direct it to the Input Port Note: All my processors are in running stage.
Input Port connected to a LogAttribute to receive the data from the Remote Process Group

Second, I have downloaded the ExecuteSQL, Remote Process Group and LogAttribute pipeline as a JSON file and named it as flow.json.raw and placed it in the conf folder and started the minifi instance.

And this the error I am facing
run-minifi.bat
2024-09-02 10:49:26,738 ERROR [main] o.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.Command Exception happened during MiNiFi startup
org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.configuration.ConfigurationChangeException: Unable to perform reload of received configuration change
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.service.MiNiFiConfigurationChangeListener.handleChange(MiNiFiConfigurationChangeListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.command.StartRunner.regenerateFlowConfiguration(StartRunner.java:279)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.command.StartRunner.start(StartRunner.java:131)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.command.StartRunner.runCommand(StartRunner.java:107)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.run(RunMiNiFi.java:133)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.RunMiNiFi.main(RunMiNiFi.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.nifi.flow.VersionedProcessGroup.getIdentifier()" because "rootGroup" is null
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.commons.service.StandardFlowEnrichService.enrichFlow(StandardFlowEnrichService.java:115)
        at org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.service.MiNiFiConfigurationChangeListener.handleChange(MiNiFiConfigurationChangeListener.java:92)
        ... 5 common frames omitted

Here is the json definition of the flow I have created.
{
    "flowContents": {
        "identifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792",
        "instanceIdentifier": "a3c3c70f-0191-1000-edb6-e2cf3fd3a7d4",
        "name": "flow",
        "comments": "",
        "position": {
            "x": -288,
            "y": 192
        },
        "processGroups": [],
        "remoteProcessGroups": [
            {
                "identifier": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187",
                "instanceIdentifier": "a37a0ea6-0191-1000-eea1-3b9e8a9dcc34",
                "name": "NiFi Flow",
                "comments": "",
                "position": {
                    "x": -280,
                    "y": 456
                },
                "targetUri": "http://localhost:8088/nifi",
                "targetUris": "http://localhost:8088/nifi",
                "communicationsTimeout": "60 sec",
                "yieldDuration": "20 sec",
                "transportProtocol": "RAW",
                "proxyHost": "",
                "proxyUser": "",
                "inputPorts": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "9221b58f-8ff5-340d-ae7b-401cc053abb0",
                        "instanceIdentifier": "d4493e75-0fbf-34dc-a6ad-f5d633d1c474",
                        "name": "FromMiNiFi",
                        "remoteGroupId": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187",
                        "concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount": 1,
                        "useCompression": false,
                        "batchSize": {},
                        "componentType": "REMOTE_INPUT_PORT",
                        "targetId": "9d7361b0-0191-1000-2493-b894111e3ef6",
                        "scheduledState": "ENABLED",
                        "groupIdentifier": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187"
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "cc5997a9-f62f-3764-9a10-d13e424a4008",
                        "instanceIdentifier": "f2b798e2-88e4-36d8-b5af-5c667f6a2360",
                        "name": "Copy of receiveSQLData",
                        "remoteGroupId": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187",
                        "concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount": 1,
                        "useCompression": false,
                        "batchSize": {},
                        "componentType": "REMOTE_INPUT_PORT",
                        "targetId": "a37f55f2-0191-1000-19c7-1260366aa0d3",
                        "scheduledState": "ENABLED",
                        "groupIdentifier": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187"
                    }
                ],
                "outputPorts": [],
                "componentType": "REMOTE_PROCESS_GROUP",
                "groupIdentifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792"
            }
        ],
        "processors": [
            {
                "identifier": "d26346ca-8682-3704-ab65-a33435b1b7d2",
                "instanceIdentifier": "a38182fb-0191-1000-54f0-10cf9ad54935",
                "name": "LogAttribute",
                "comments": "",
                "position": {
                    "x": 481.0553418104679,
                    "y": 419.9186557338876
                },
                "type": "org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute",
                "bundle": {
                    "group": "org.apache.nifi",
                    "artifact": "nifi-standard-nar",
                    "version": "1.23.2"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Log prefix": null,
                    "character-set": "UTF-8",
                    "Log FlowFile Properties": "true",
                    "Log Level": "info",
                    "attributes-to-ignore-regex": null,
                    "Attributes to Ignore": null,
                    "Attributes to Log": null,
                    "attributes-to-log-regex": ".*",
                    "Output Format": "Line per Attribute",
                    "Log Payload": "false"
                },
                "propertyDescriptors": {
                    "Log prefix": {
                        "name": "Log prefix",
                        "displayName": "Log prefix",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "character-set": {
                        "name": "character-set",
                        "displayName": "Character Set",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Log FlowFile Properties": {
                        "name": "Log FlowFile Properties",
                        "displayName": "Log FlowFile Properties",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Log Level": {
                        "name": "Log Level",
                        "displayName": "Log Level",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "attributes-to-ignore-regex": {
                        "name": "attributes-to-ignore-regex",
                        "displayName": "Attributes to Ignore by Regular Expression",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Attributes to Ignore": {
                        "name": "Attributes to Ignore",
                        "displayName": "Attributes to Ignore",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Attributes to Log": {
                        "name": "Attributes to Log",
                        "displayName": "Attributes to Log",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "attributes-to-log-regex": {
                        "name": "attributes-to-log-regex",
                        "displayName": "Attributes to Log by Regular Expression",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Output Format": {
                        "name": "Output Format",
                        "displayName": "Output Format",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Log Payload": {
                        "name": "Log Payload",
                        "displayName": "Log Payload",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    }
                },
                "style": {},
                "schedulingPeriod": "0 sec",
                "schedulingStrategy": "TIMER_DRIVEN",
                "executionNode": "ALL",
                "penaltyDuration": "30 sec",
                "yieldDuration": "1 sec",
                "bulletinLevel": "WARN",
                "runDurationMillis": 25,
                "concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount": 1,
                "autoTerminatedRelationships": [
                    "success"
                ],
                "scheduledState": "ENABLED",
                "retryCount": 10,
                "retriedRelationships": [],
                "backoffMechanism": "PENALIZE_FLOWFILE",
                "maxBackoffPeriod": "10 mins",
                "componentType": "PROCESSOR",
                "groupIdentifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "75f885a8-f584-36cf-9d90-b92a7cad5af0",
                "instanceIdentifier": "a3644f7e-0191-1000-b197-019d8ad10c41",
                "name": "ExecuteSQL",
                "comments": "",
                "position": {
                    "x": -136,
                    "y": 64
                },
                "type": "org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL",
                "bundle": {
                    "group": "org.apache.nifi",
                    "artifact": "nifi-standard-nar",
                    "version": "1.23.2"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "esql-max-rows": "0",
                    "dbf-default-precision": "10",
                    "Max Wait Time": "0 seconds",
                    "Database Connection Pooling Service": "822e5ffc-8f36-3466-8ecc-5f319e4980c8",
                    "sql-post-query": null,
                    "esql-auto-commit": "true",
                    "dbf-user-logical-types": "false",
                    "dbf-default-scale": "0",
                    "sql-pre-query": null,
                    "compression-format": "NONE",
                    "esql-output-batch-size": "0",
                    "esql-fetch-size": "0",
                    "SQL select query": "select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from public.tjavatest;",
                    "dbf-normalize": "false"
                },
                "propertyDescriptors": {
                    "esql-max-rows": {
                        "name": "esql-max-rows",
                        "displayName": "Max Rows Per Flow File",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "dbf-default-precision": {
                        "name": "dbf-default-precision",
                        "displayName": "Default Decimal Precision",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Max Wait Time": {
                        "name": "Max Wait Time",
                        "displayName": "Max Wait Time",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "Database Connection Pooling Service": {
                        "name": "Database Connection Pooling Service",
                        "displayName": "Database Connection Pooling Service",
                        "identifiesControllerService": true,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "sql-post-query": {
                        "name": "sql-post-query",
                        "displayName": "SQL Post-Query",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "esql-auto-commit": {
                        "name": "esql-auto-commit",
                        "displayName": "Set Auto Commit",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "dbf-user-logical-types": {
                        "name": "dbf-user-logical-types",
                        "displayName": "Use Avro Logical Types",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "dbf-default-scale": {
                        "name": "dbf-default-scale",
                        "displayName": "Default Decimal Scale",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "sql-pre-query": {
                        "name": "sql-pre-query",
                        "displayName": "SQL Pre-Query",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "compression-format": {
                        "name": "compression-format",
                        "displayName": "Compression Format",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "esql-output-batch-size": {
                        "name": "esql-output-batch-size",
                        "displayName": "Output Batch Size",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "esql-fetch-size": {
                        "name": "esql-fetch-size",
                        "displayName": "Fetch Size",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "SQL select query": {
                        "name": "SQL select query",
                        "displayName": "SQL select query",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    },
                    "dbf-normalize": {
                        "name": "dbf-normalize",
                        "displayName": "Normalize Table/Column Names",
                        "identifiesControllerService": false,
                        "sensitive": false
                    }
                },
                "style": {},
                "schedulingPeriod": "0 sec",
                "schedulingStrategy": "TIMER_DRIVEN",
                "executionNode": "ALL",
                "penaltyDuration": "30 sec",
                "yieldDuration": "1 sec",
                "bulletinLevel": "WARN",
                "runDurationMillis": 0,
                "concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount": 1,
                "autoTerminatedRelationships": [],
                "scheduledState": "ENABLED",
                "retryCount": 10,
                "retriedRelationships": [],
                "backoffMechanism": "PENALIZE_FLOWFILE",
                "maxBackoffPeriod": "10 mins",
                "componentType": "PROCESSOR",
                "groupIdentifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792"
            }
        ],
        "inputPorts": [],
        "outputPorts": [],
        "connections": [
            {
                "identifier": "a4c0a496-5351-3cc3-a4fb-4aadcfb93ac4",
                "instanceIdentifier": "a3819773-0191-1000-47c5-0adb24a80f96",
                "name": "",
                "source": {
                    "id": "75f885a8-f584-36cf-9d90-b92a7cad5af0",
                    "type": "PROCESSOR",
                    "groupId": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792",
                    "name": "ExecuteSQL",
                    "comments": "",
                    "instanceIdentifier": "a3644f7e-0191-1000-b197-019d8ad10c41"
                },
                "destination": {
                    "id": "d26346ca-8682-3704-ab65-a33435b1b7d2",
                    "type": "PROCESSOR",
                    "groupId": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792",
                    "name": "LogAttribute",
                    "comments": "",
                    "instanceIdentifier": "a38182fb-0191-1000-54f0-10cf9ad54935"
                },
                "labelIndex": 1,
                "zIndex": 0,
                "selectedRelationships": [
                    "failure"
                ],
                "backPressureObjectThreshold": 10000,
                "backPressureDataSizeThreshold": "1 GB",
                "flowFileExpiration": "0 sec",
                "prioritizers": [],
                "bends": [],
                "loadBalanceStrategy": "DO_NOT_LOAD_BALANCE",
                "partitioningAttribute": "",
                "loadBalanceCompression": "DO_NOT_COMPRESS",
                "componentType": "CONNECTION",
                "groupIdentifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "51ef2902-0ce4-3254-8398-0f07b666ec6b",
                "instanceIdentifier": "a380e710-0191-1000-5968-000a66ac2604",
                "name": "",
                "source": {
                    "id": "75f885a8-f584-36cf-9d90-b92a7cad5af0",
                    "type": "PROCESSOR",
                    "groupId": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792",
                    "name": "ExecuteSQL",
                    "comments": "",
                    "instanceIdentifier": "a3644f7e-0191-1000-b197-019d8ad10c41"
                },
                "destination": {
                    "id": "cc5997a9-f62f-3764-9a10-d13e424a4008",
                    "type": "REMOTE_INPUT_PORT",
                    "groupId": "704a77a9-410d-3114-a724-b37bdc242187",
                    "name": "Copy of receiveSQLData",
                    "instanceIdentifier": "f2b798e2-88e4-36d8-b5af-5c667f6a2360"
                },
                "labelIndex": 1,
                "zIndex": 0,
                "selectedRelationships": [
                    "success"
                ],
                "backPressureObjectThreshold": 10000,
                "backPressureDataSizeThreshold": "1 GB",
                "flowFileExpiration": "0 sec",
                "prioritizers": [],
                "bends": [],
                "loadBalanceStrategy": "DO_NOT_LOAD_BALANCE",
                "partitioningAttribute": "",
                "loadBalanceCompression": "DO_NOT_COMPRESS",
                "componentType": "CONNECTION",
                "groupIdentifier": "e112dc88-89fb-3b93-ae94-558da67bb792"
            }
        ],
        "labels": [],
        "funnels": [],
        "controllerServices": [],
        "variables": {},
        "defaultFlowFileExpiration": "0 sec",
        "defaultBackPressureObjectThreshold": 10000,
        "defaultBackPressureDataSizeThreshold": "1 GB",
        "componentType": "PROCESS_GROUP",
        "flowFileOutboundPolicy": "STREAM_WHEN_AVAILABLE",
        "flowFileConcurrency": "UNBOUNDED"
    },
    "externalControllerServices": {
        "822e5ffc-8f36-3466-8ecc-5f319e4980c8": {
            "identifier": "822e5ffc-8f36-3466-8ecc-5f319e4980c8",
            "name": "DBCPConnectionPool"
        }
    },
    "parameterContexts": [],
    "flowEncodingVersion": "1.0",
    "parameterProviders": [],
    "latest": false
}



After going through the quick-start I got to know that there are some nars that need to be included in the lib folder of minifi even though they are supported out of  box. ExecuteSQL is one of them so I included the nar from the NiFi and solved the error. Even though the data flow is not generated.
